# spyder (python) do not open (it is not giving any error actually )

Tags: spyder

[image]

problem: I have created a python virtual env and typed spyder. when i hit enter it does not open and do'nt even show any error.

previously it was working fine.
I have tried these things
1.updating conda and spyder (nothing happens)
2. I am able to open it outside of virtual env

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: Spyder fails to start without any error given. For me the problem surfaced after I installed some new packages from conda-forge, one of them `matplotlib`. When I installed matplotlib from the regular conda channels, the problem went away.

```
conda install matplotlib

Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\robk\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - matplotlib


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    qt-5.9.6                   |   vc14h62aca36_0        92.5 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    matplotlib: 2.2.2-py36_1          conda-forge --> 2.2.2-py36h153e9ff_1
    pyqt:       5.6.0-py36_2                      --> 5.9.2-py36h1aa27d4_0
    qt:         5.6.2-vc14h6f8c307_12             --> 5.9.6-vc14h62aca36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Rob.it is working now..just by installing matplotlib lib as you mentioned above